# How to move header to extreme top of page?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Using page geometry as follows:

```
\geometry{a4paper,inner=12mm,outer=10mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=5mm}%
```

Header Code:

```
\rhead{\color{green(munsell)}\normalsize{Visit Summary}}%
\lhead{\color{green(munsell)}\normalsize{Visit Index}}%
```

the headers are set using `fancyhead`.

[image: Able to set header at this position on page.]

[image: Want header a bit up like in this image.]

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the `top` value will move the headers up or down:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,inner=12mm,outer=10mm,top=12.5mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=5mm}%

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\color{green}\normalsize{Visit Summary}}% 
\lhead{\color{green}\normalsize{Visit Index}}%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```